# Multidimensional arrays in Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to create/simulate a 3D (or higher dimension) array in Perl?
I've tried to search on the web, but found nothing.

Comment: "I've tried to search on the web, but found nothing" You've done no such thing. If I Google for `multi-dimensional arrays in perl` it comes up with dozens of relevant pages, the first of which is [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=90647). Please make some effort before you post on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at [perldoc perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).  That stands for "Perl lists of lists", which is a name for a type of multi-dimensional data-structures.

Consider `@array`.  If instead of placing simple values in `@array`'s elements you place references to arrays, you now have a data structure that can be treated like an array of arrays, or a 2-dimensional array.  Want 3d?  No problem.  You can go to whatever depth you wish.

```
@array = (
    [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
    [ 'D', 'E', 'F' ],
    [ 'G', 'H', 'I' ],
); # A 2D structure represented as a LoLs.

@array = (
    [ [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ], [ 'D', 'E', 'F' ], [ 'G', 'H', 'I' ] ],
    [ [ 'J', 'K', 'L' ], [ 'M', 'N', 'O' ], [ 'P', 'Q', 'R' ] ],
    [ [ 'S', 'T', 'U' ], [ 'V', 'W', 'X' ], [ 'Y', 'Z', 'a' ] ],
); # A 3D structure.

@array = (
    [ [ [ 'A', 'B' ], [ 'C', 'D' ] ], [ [ 'E', 'F' ], [ 'G', 'H' ] ] ],
    [ [ [ 'I', 'J' ], [ 'K', 'L' ] ], [ [ 'M', 'N' ], [ 'O', 'P' ] ] ],
); # A 4D structure.
```

Your imagination and available RAM are the only constraints on how complex the data structure can become or how many dimensions it can hold.  It doesn't even have to be uniform:

```
@array = ( [ 'a', 'b' ], 'c', [ 'd', 'e', [ 'f', 'g', 'h' ] ] );
```

How about a linked list:

```
$head->[ 'a', [ 'b', [ 'c', [ 'd', [ 'e', [ 'f', [ 'g', undef ] ] ] ] ] ] ];
```

And all those are only dealing with simple scalar values combined with array-references.  You also get to play with hash references, code references, glob references, object references, and even scalar references.  There's a lot of power available.

Additional useful reading materials are [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), and [perldoc perldsc (Data Structure Cookbook)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), as well as the following books: [Intermediate Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012689.do), [Programming Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do), and even the somewhat dated [Mastering Algorithms with Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565923980.do).

Comment: `"Your imagination and available RAM are the only constraints on how complex the data structure can become or how many dimensions it can hold"` - I recall reading somewhere (was it the Llama?) that the limit on dimensions was 27. Not sure if I remember correctly though.

Comment: @Zaid - `perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper eval "["x5000 . 1 . "]"x5000'` works just fine, even on v5.6

Comment: @Zaid Just check it.  Not correct.  My "Linked list" example goes to seven levels here, but could easily go to as many levels as your memory can sustain.

Answer (score 0):

A two-dimensional array would be an array with references to other arrays. [perldoc perllol](http://p3rl.org/lol) has a detailed how-to.

From this basic principle more complex data structures can be made, like arrays of hashes of arrays of hashes of… you get the idea.